# flutter: why my Positionned() widget doesn't showing?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack

I added a positionned widget, but its content is not showing. I put a text outside the positionned widget and it shows. Can you help me please? (sorry ,I can't add images I don't have enough reputation :) my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Text("test"),
      Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
          height: 100,
            width: 100,
              child: Text("test2"),

        )
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you miss the Scaffold in the beginning and the text will be in the top left near the edge and the other below
Try this please:

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Text("test"),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: Text("test2"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, when I run, at the bottom of my screen I have a big yellow and black band. Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you added the Scaffold on top?

Comment: Yes,I’ve added it

Comment: Share a photo for that please @ChevelevPhilippe